# Pyinstaller error related to pandas library during freezing a code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm using python 3 to freeze a code.

Error message:

```
    C:\ENV_Anemopy\dist>AnemoPy_1_0.exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "AnemoPy_1_0.py", line 18, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader    \pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 26, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 37, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 100, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4390, in <module>
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10138, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 14, in <module>
    File "c:\users\ita\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3hamod\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 687, in load_module
    File "pandas\_libs\skiplist.pxd", line 31, in init pandas._libs.window
    ImportError: No module named skiplist
    [11248] Failed to execute script AnemoPy_1_0
```

I've tested my procedure with a hello world and all was ok. Apparently the problem comes from pandas. BTW, I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I had similar **ImportError** with **pyinstaller** version 3.6 and **pandas** version 1.0.5. Apparently, in my case, the problem was related to **pyinstaller**'s handling of **pandas** latest version. So after I manually installed an older version (1.0.1) of **pandas**, my issue was gone. You may try it as well.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```